# Newbie trying to understand PHP constants

Tags: php, constants

I'm a PHP newbie trying to debug someone's code. The very first line of the code has what I think is a constant as shown below:

```
<?php
set_time_limit (0);
require_once (SITE_PATH. '/server/php/libs/dbase/handler.php');
```

I have written a debug statement and I have gotten a null.

```
echo "SITE_PATH"
```

How should PHP constants be declared. Should'nt the require statement be `$SITE_PATH` instead of `SITE_PATH`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is clearly explained in documentation

Comment: http://se2.php.net/constants

Comment: considering _constant's_ aren't _variables_, what makes you say that `SITE_PATH` should be `$SITE_PATH` -> the `$` indicates a variable, not a constant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

php constants must be defined as :

```
define('SITE_PATH','http://localhost/site');
```

and are used as :

```
echo SITE_PATH;
```

Look at this : **[php constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php)**